# Integral difficulties (attempt included)

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I am having difficulties with the following integral. I began working on it and thought I had obtained the answer, but when I went to graph it I received an integral of 1. I obtained the same answer when I went to double check it on WolframAlpha.

[image]

Here is my working. Would anyone be able to please push me in the right direction?

Let u = 1 + ln(t); du = dt/t

The integral then becomes:

∫du/u^2

= -1/u

= -1/(1 + |ln(t)) from e^-1 to e

=-1/2 - (-1/2)

= 0

Comment: Have you kept track of the absolute value? Try WA-ing the integral without the absolute value and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is $\int_{e^{-1}}^{e}\frac{dt}{t(1 + |\ln t|)^2}$

Sub $t = e^x$

$$\int_{e^{-1}}^{e}\frac{dt}{t(1 + |\ln t|)^2} = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{e^xdx}{e^x(1+|x|)^2} = \int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} + \int_{-1}^0 \frac{dx}{(1-x)^2} = -\frac{1}{2} + 1 + 1 - \frac{1}{2} = 1$$

Comment: I think you have been a bit hasty... Since $(1+x)²$ and $(1+x²)$ are different...

Comment: Sorry, spotted the error as soon as I made it (before I saw your comment), but thanks. Am out of time, so left the split integral for the OP to evaluate.

Comment: You did not correct the error, you added another one... There are two issues, one with absolute value, the other with the expansion of $(1+x)²$. Just look at the value of $(1-x²)$ for $x=-1$ (or $x=1$)...

Comment: Sorry, rushing to do some other work. Correct now? :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{e^{-1}}^e\dfrac{dt}{t(1+|\ln t|)^2}$$ use the substitution $$x=\ln t.$$ Then $dx=\dfrac{dt}{t}$ and $x \to 1,-1$ as $t\to e,e^{-1}.$
Now our integral become to $$\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{dx}{(1+|x|)^2}=\int_{-1}^0\dfrac{dx}{(1-x)^2}+\int_{0}^1\dfrac{dx}{(1+x)^2}.$$ I think you can continue from here.

Comment: Don't forget to use the absolute value of $x$, not $x$... Otherwise you have an issue....

Comment: @Martigan; thanks. I'l edit it.

Comment: It seems you made a mistake in your answer. The first integral is wrong, $-x^2$ instead of $+x^2$. Also the integrand is even so the answer is twice the second integral.